# C11 thread-safety with respect to functions that return pointers to static buffers

Tags: c, multithreading, language-lawyer, c11

Consider functions like `localtime` in the C standard library which return a pointer to a (historically) static buffer. Does C11 make these buffers thread-local?

Per 7.1.4 in C11:

> Unless explicitly stated otherwise in the detailed descriptions that follow, library functions shall prevent data races as follows: A library function shall not directly or indirectly access objects accessible by threads other than the current thread unless the objects are accessed directly or indirectly via the function's arguments. A library function shall not directly or indirectly modify objects accessible by threads other than the current thread unless the objects are accessed directly or indirectly via the function's non-const arguments. Implementations may share their own internal objects between threads if the objects are not visible to users and are protected against data races.

Consider for example `localtime`. The `struct tm` to which its return value points does not seem to qualify as an "internal object" since it's accessible to the caller, so it seems that an invocation of `localtime` in another thread may not clobber the result previously returned in the first thread. This would imply that `localtime` needs to use a different buffer for each thread.

However, nowhere does the standard specify an end to the lifetime of the object whose address is returned, and I see no reason a program continuing to use this `struct tm` after the calling thread terminates would be invalid. Thus, the object cannot have thread storage duration.

The only way I can find that an implementation could meet all the requirements is to leak memory all over the place, which is surely not what's intended. Am I missing something obvious, or is C11's treatment of thread-safety with respect to legacy interfaces really this poorly thought-out?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

... `unless explicitly stated otherwise`: The introductory chapter of  `7.27.3 Time conversion functions` explicitly states that these functions are not supposed to avoid data races. (As is the case for many other library functions.)

There are derived function with `_s` suffix in the bounds checking extension in normative annex K that are designed to avoid race conditions.

Comment: OK, I looked in the specific documentation for the functions, but not the intro. Looks like you found what I was missing.

Comment: You might want to add that the annex is optional, implementations are rare, non-conformant, and / or inefficient, and there are good reasons to reject them even if they would fix those deal-breakers. See also [tag:tr24731].